# kattis: why does my output contain my input?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to attempt a question on kattis [Left beehind](https://open.kattis.com/problems/leftbeehind) and my output is correct but somehow my input gets written with the output which im so confused about. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to get rid of the numbers in my output?

here is my code: (im using javascript)

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var nums = line.split(' ');
    var x = parseInt(nums[0]);
    var y = parseInt(nums[1]);
    
    if (x==0 && y==0 ) {
      return;
    }
    
    if (x+y==13) {
        console.log("Never speak again.")
    }
    else if (y>x) {
        console.log("Left Beehind.")
    }
    else if ( x > y ) {
        console.log ("To the convention.")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Undecided.")
    }
});
```

and this my output

```
17 3
To the convention.
13 14
Left Beehind.
8 5
Never speak again.
44 44
Undecided.
0 0
```

Comment: Have you checked you don't have a extra `console.log()` in a different file some where that might be logging input?

Comment: I don't see that there's any problem here. When you type into the interactive prompt, the numbers appear as you enter them, but they're not being printed. This code works fine if you submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is being written with your output because you specified `process.stdout`, which is your NodeJS console, as an output for the `readline` interface.

So, `readline` is successfully reading the lines, emitting the `line` event for each line it receives/finds, then you are performing some logic and printing some text using `console.log` (which in turn uses `process.stdout` to print to the NodeJS console). Finally, `readline` is streaming the lines to the same output.

Remove the `output` option and it should work as expected.

Comment: I don't see that this is related. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#class-interfaceconstructor) say "The `output` stream is used to print prompts for user `input` that arrives on, and is read from, the input stream." I think OP is just confused that their input typing also shows up on the terminal. If you submit the original code to Kattis, it accepts it without this modification. If you want to know what `output:` does, try adding `rl.prompt()` to the code, then add and remove the `output:` code and you'll see the difference. Without `output:`, it doesn't show the `>` prompt.